# Why is there no vector(size_type n, const Allocator& alloc) in C++11?

Tags: c++, vector, c++11, allocator

In C++11, std::vector has the constructor `vector(size_type n)` which will default construct `n` items in place, which can be used with default constructible, movable, non-copyable classes.

However, unlike every other vector constructor, there is no variant that takes an allocator, and I have resorted to the following:

```
// Foo is default constructible and moveable, but not copyable
const int n = 10; // Want 10 default constructed Foos
std::vector<Foo, CustomAllocator> foos(allocator);
foos.reserve(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
   foos.emplace_back();
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this? Is there a specific reason `vector(size_type n, const Allocator& alloc)` was omitted from the standard?

Comment: Sounds like a defect in the specification. File a report on it, if one isn't there already.

Comment: @NicolBolas is there a documents that describes the process for filing a report?

Comment: Never mind. See my post.

Comment: For reporting defects: http://www.comeaucomputing.com/csc/faq.html#B13

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After thinking about it, it might not be a defect after all.

It is possible that `allocator_type` and `value_type` are perversely *the same* type. In that case, which function would `vector(3, alloc)` call? The constructor that takes a default value to copy-initialize into all of the elements, or the one that takes a size and an allocator? That's ambiguous, and thus a compile error.

Comment: Yikes! I don't think I would have ever thought of that.

Comment: Easily solvable with [`std::allocator_arg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_arg), which is already used in other places (e.g., `std::tuple`). The allocator version would then be `vector(3, std::allocator_arg, alloc)`.

Comment: The standard library often has to avoid using the same number of parameters in overloads of functions with templated parameters. For example this is why they ultimately did not introduce a variadic std::max and instead went with a version that takes an initializer list. A variadic version would be impossible to implement in an easy to use fashion while still allowing for custom comparison.

Comment: @bames53: Very nice. I was half imagining that there was a reason for the non-existence of that overload. Also, I never knew that `max` can take a custom predicate!

Comment: @bames53: Sadly, that's also part of the reason why the committee seems a bit reluctant to adopt ranges. :/ The range overloads with predicates would interfere with the iterator overloads without predicates. Also the reason why there's `std::copy` and `std::copy_if` instead of another overload.

Answer (score 7):

First, instead of your `reserve`/loop thingy, you can simply use `resize` to achieve what your imagined constructor would do:

```
const int n = 10;
std::vector<Foo, Alloc> foos(allocator);
foo.resize(n);
```

Another option is to use the three argument version of the `size_type n` constructor:

```
const int n = 10;
std::vector<Foo, Alloc> foos(n, Foo(), allocator);
```

Though this actually *copy* constructs into the elements, which may or may not be acceptable.

On the rationale? No idea. Probably overlooked.

Comment: Thanks. I knew I must be overlooking an easier way.